# Is it possible to separate data by keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

From the database I get the data in the following style:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => edit_sites
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => view_sites
        )
)
```

Does Laravel have any built-in methods for obtaining data by the keys like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => view_sites
            [1] => edit_sites
        )

)
```

or i need to do it by myself ?

Comment: from where that `3` came?

Comment: @itachi soory, my mistake.

Comment: What about other properties that can be there? Maybe you need `lists` method instead. What do you need that for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is none, you have to do it by yourself albeit an easy one really.

```
$processedData = array();  

foreach($dbData as $row) {
    foreach($row as $dbKey => $value) {
         $processedData[$dbKey][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the data back as a raw array (which you seem to be), then `array_pluck` will do most of what you want:

For example:

```
// you could use this wherever you needed the specific lists
$ids = array_pluck($results, 'id'); // [ 1, 2 ]

// or if you wanted the array exactly as asked for in the question:
$sortedArray = array(
  'id' => array_pluck($results, 'id'),
  'name' => array_pluck($results, 'name')
);
// [
//   'id' => [1,2],
//   'name' => [ 'view_sites', 'edit_sites' ]
// ]
```

If you are getting the results as some kind of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class (say, from an `Eloquent` query), then you can use the `lists` method on the `Collection` as an alias to `array_pluck`

```
$results->lists('id'); // [ 1, 2 ]
```